# Trouble Linking Newly Created View to View Controller Class in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm creating an iOS app and have made a number of different views in Storyboard as well as a number of .swift files which represent different ViewController objects. For some reason, I am unable to figure out how to link the views I've created with the different ViewController (i.e. .swift files).

I know I am supposed to drag or control-drag and drop from the views in the Storyboard to the "Custom Class" dropdown on the right side (or something very similar to this). However I am unable to see the option to make the ViewControllers a custom class.

Can anyone help figure out what the issue is? I feel like it is something minor unless I'm missing something and I've done this pretty easily before but am blanking for quite some time now.

In the image below, you can see that I was able to link a few of the viewcontrollers in the Storyboard, however I am no longer able to link the bottom two "View Controller Scenes" (which I created afterwards to other ViewController.swift files I made later.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect your `ViewController.swift` files to the `ViewController`s, do the following:

1. Select the `ViewController` in Storyboard.
2. Navigate to the **Identity inspector** on the right panel.
3. In the field **Class**, select the dropdown arrow.
4. Select your `ViewController.swift` file that you would like to link to the `ViewController` in Storyboard.

This is a very easy step to miss. I've done it myself many times before. For future reference, when creating a new `ViewController` in Storyboard, connect it to its `ViewController.swift` file as soon as possible. Otherwise, it may result in incorrect Interface Builder connections, etc.

Comment: Hi - thanks I figured out the problem and its really stupid. I knew that step but I gave the class name a slightly different title than what I defined in its source code so I wasn't locating it in the Identity Inspector bc I was expecting to see a different name. I didn't notice it because the names all seemed similar to the default processes listed there already

Comment: @user2603139 OK, glad you figured it out. Sometimes Storyboard can make it difficult with connections and all.

Comment: No worries - I read your response and tried to do what you wrote and finally noticed it this time (even though I knew I had done it already a few times). So I think your response was both right and contributed to helping me debug the issue